# How to fix TypeError: penup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when trying to make a border on Tkinter

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm getting this error:
TypeError: penup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

From this code:(I'm expecting to get a border on my window but I get an error.)

```
    #Draw border
    mypen = turtle.Turtle
    mypen.penup()
    mypen.setposition(-300,-300)
    mypen.pendown()
    mypen.pensize(3)

I'm expecting to get a border on my window but I get an error.
```

Comment: You forgot to instantiate the object. `turtle.Turtle` should be `turtle.Turtle()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `mypen = turtle.Turtle` is getting a reference to the class itself and not an object of the class. The method `penup()` requires you to have an object of the class to call that as it is not static. You can solve this by changing your first line to:

```
mypen = turtle.Turtle()
```